# Session expires when using jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: session, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using sessions in the administrative part of my website to check whether the user is logged in or not. My problem is that the session seem to expire suddenly.

I've tried to track down the problem as it only expires when some of the pages were refreshed. At last it came down to the datepicker that I am using from jQuery UI. If I give an input element the datepicker-class, then the session expires when the page is refreshed. If I remove the class="datepicker" from the input element, then I can refresh the page all I want without any problems.

This is the input element, I'm not entering anything in it, simply refreshing the page without any changes done.

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text" name="expiring" value="" />
```

I don't know if the session expires or is destoyed, all I know is that the session-element that is used to check login-details becomes empty.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I think jQuery date picker is not culprit as it merely add ability to select date from calendar & some validation and that too on client-side only. Please check if input has some server-side event bind on change of value which triggers some function that can clear or abandon the session.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not entering anything in the input element, simply refreshing the page without any changes done. I can't see how datepicker could do anything either, but if I remove the id, the session works fine.

Comment: Is this page is Login page itself? removed id??? or class="datepicker" ?? any changes in web.config meanwhile ??

Comment: I tried to switch between id and class to see if it did any difference, but it's the same. So I tried both class="datepicker" and id="datepicker". This is not the login page, just a page with a form. I didn't change anything else, only the class/id. Even switched back and forth a couple of times to be sure that it was the class/id that made the session expire.